# How to check if csv file contains string?

Tags: python, csv

Im trying to create a simple word-game and I need to check if words that player writes in are in the dictionary.

For now, Im able to check it row by row, but its not very effective so I hope there is a better way

```
import csv

word = raw_input('write your word')

def dict_test(word):
    with open('/home/patryk/Pulpit/slownik.csv', 'r') as dictionary:
        reader = csv.reader(dictionary, delimiter = ' ')

        for row in reader:

             if word not in row:
                print word + ' it doesnt exist in dictionary'
             elif word in row:
                print word + ' ### OK ### '
dict_test(word)
```

Comment: Is your csv file static or does that gets dynamically updated by some other process (other than your script ?).

Comment: Anshul's comment is relevant because you should probably just read the dictionary at the beginning of your game, so you only have to do that once, rather than each time the dict_test function is called.

Comment: What is `slowo` in your example code?

Comment: Can you post a small sample of what your csv looks like? Is it just two columns (word and definition) or is there more fluff?

Comment: `if word not in row:` statement only checks to see if the word in that one row, not the whole dictionary/csv file.

Comment: @Anshul: csv is static

Comment: @Brian: Just one column that contains words

Comment: @martineau: its 'word' in Polish, i've forgotten to change it after ctrl+v ;)

and I know about what you mentioned and as I said, Im looking for a better way

Comment: If your csv file isn't too big, you could read the whole thing into memory once as a long string and put that into a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html?highlight=stringio#StringIO) object and then afterward use that with `csv.reader()` instead of the real file. This would likely be **much** quicker and not require many other changes to your existing code.

Comment: @martineau: Im not sure if 297949 rows in csv is 'too big', is it? :)

Comment: @Patr01, assuming there's 6 columns and an average of 10 bytes per column, it's only 17MB

Comment: @TankorSmash: Just one column, as I said, and 4,4 mb, im going to try the StringIO, thanks martineau!

Comment: In my opinion that's not even close to too big...

Answer (score 0):

If the csv file can be read into a list with one word in each element of the list searching it can be done with `"word" in dictionary_list`. I the list is ordered alphabetically, then faster searching it can be done with a binary search. The bisect module uses a binary search, and includes a recipe for an index function:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def index(a, x):
'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
i = bisect_left(a, x)
if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
    return i
raise ValueError
```

You could then use this

```
try:
    i = index(dictionary_list,word):
    print word + "== Ok =="
except ValueError:
    print word, "doesn't exist in dictionary"
```

But I expect this is overkill: reading the dictionary into memory would be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file is a static one (no process other than your main script is updating it), then you are essentially looking for a `set of words` (you can use set - I would give an example using dict (which I don't recall but I think is faster than using set))

You can do the following

```
import csv

word_dict = {}

def dict_test(word):
   if word_dict.get(word):
      print word + "### OK ###"
   else:
      print word + "is not in dictionary"

def load_words():
    with open('/home/patryk/Pulpit/slownik.csv', 'r') as dictionary:
        reader = csv.reader(dictionary, delimiter = ' ')

        for row in reader:
             words = row.split()
             for word in words:
                 word_dict[word] = 1

# Load all the contect of csv file ONCE
load_words() 
# Now continue asking user
word = raw_input('write your word')
dict_test(word)
```